# Rails learning simple ajax/ jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, ajax

Hey guys backend guy here messing with some front end stuff.

So for right now I have these three files:

a new view:

```
<div id= "savings-list">
  <%= render "savings/list", locals: { savings: @savings } %> 
</div >

<div>
  <a  href= "" id= "new-random-savings-btn" > Random </a>
</div>
```

the partial:

JS ajax json:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var newSavingsBtn = $("#new-random-savings-btn");

  var updateSavings = function(newSavings){
    console.log(newSavings);
  }

  var appendSavings = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var request = $.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      type: "GET",
      url: "/savings/random",
      data: ""
    })

    request.done(updateSavings);
  }

  newSavingsBtn.on("click", appendSavings);
})
```

Simple controller returning some temp json data:

```
class SavingsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def random
    @savings = random_savings.to_json

    render json: @savings
  end

  private

  def random_savings
    temp_data.shuffle.take(2)
  end

  def temp_data
    [
      { name: "coffee", price: "2.99" },
      { name: "tacos", price: "1.99" },
      { name: "smoking", price: "5.99" },
      { name: "1000 tv channels", price: "120.99" },
    ]
  end
end
```

Goal is to update elements on the view page. However the href seems to just refresh the page. The json is getting called, but then the refresh seems to happen? What's the best way to do this and get it working?

Comment: so the ajax is performing how you want you just want to stop the page from refreshing too?

Comment: The method is `preventDefault` not `PreventDefault`

Comment: Also, what is `data: { data }`? You're not defining a `data` var anywhere I can see and You're not using es2015 standard are you?

Comment: @Mike so I just got to that part. trying to do this step by step. updated question to reflect current state. If I have '@savings' which is just a json string how do I update it with the new data? find the element with jquery and then just update it with the new info?

Comment: Well that's the predicament for pretty much every web application these days right? Doing that will essentially duplicate your rendering logic in 2 places (ERB & JS). You can do a few things here. 1) reload the entire page to make use of the Rails ERB templating. 2) Render the list via ajax requests after the initial page load 3) Write your entire front end in a single page application in JS, using rails as an API. I whole-heartedly advocate for #3 in this day and age, but it's a tad bit more complex. #2 is probably a bit more pragmatic for what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: Here's a great resource if you're stuck: http://angular-rails.com/

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want the page to refresh you need to change this

```
event.PreventDefault();
```

to this

```
event.preventDefault();
```